# ActionScript-3 physics libraries

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, physics-engine

I want to write a game in which there will be some balls on the stage, that will move randomly. They must have unique starting speed and angle and should interfere with each other just like real billiard balls. Is there any physics engine in AS3 that might be useful for this purpose, or will I have to write and model their behavior from the scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, doing so "from scratch" isn't really much of a challenge if you know what to do.  if you're interested in learning i would suggest you pick up Keith Peters' [Foundation ActionScript 3.0 Animation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597915) book.  one benefit from studying the lessons in the book (and perhaps [the book's sequel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216085)) is that all of the algorithms and logic are easily portable to other languages.

that being said, i believe the most popular physics engine for Flash currently is the popular C++ engine Box2D, which was recently ported to AS3 using Adobe's Alchemy.  included in the ActionScript port is a "World Construction Kit" component for Flash Professional.

more here:  [Box2d Flash Alchemy Port + World Construction Kit](http://www.sideroller.com/wck/)

Comment: thank you, i took the look at this book, i think it's exactly what i need, i mean actionscript animation is very important part of game programming. thank you, again, i think i'll use this book :-)

Comment: it's a great book.  definitely one of my favorites.  while the information in the book is still useful in Flash, the Foundation book was written in 2007 when Flash Player 9 was current.  the sequel to the book was released to address Flash Player 10+, so you should definitely get both.  in fact, the first chapter of the sequel discusses more advanced collision detection that you will certainly find helpful.

Comment: i noticed in another one of your questions that you claim to not know how to code in ActionScript 3.0 yet.  the books i've mentioned do not necessarily teach you AS3.  i think your best bet would be to get a copy of Colin Moock's Essential ActionScript 3.0 - http://goo.gl/e28DR - largely considered the AS3 Bible, it's a big book that cover's lots of ground but once you finish you should be all set.  there's also the ActionScript 3.0 Quick Reference Guide - http://goo.gl/ITNdc - which covers the basics and is much lighter, but only knowing the basics does have its disadvantages.

Comment: actually, I do know some AS3, anyway, I already have my main study-book that is very general and does not contain any code for some specific tasks that I have to solve. that's why I needed some more detailed book about AS animation... i already found what i needed in the book you showed me.